# move constructor for pointer type?

Tags: c++, c++11

This is a simple question but I can't manage to find it on google:

Is there a special move constructor for integral type(including pointers)

For instance if I do:

```
int* a = new int(2);
int* b = std::move(a);
```

Is it guaranteed to point to NULL? How about if a and b were `int`?

Comment: Your language implies that you would expect `a` to be NULL if it did have a special move constructor.  Why?  Move constructors for normal classes don't make that kind of guarantee either.

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley I was thinking that maybe a would be set to NULL so if I ever need to delete the pointer, it wouldn't have any effect (as the value as been moved from)

Comment: The move constructor just needs to leave the RHS in a state where it is safe to either destroy(i.e. go out of scope), or reassign (or some other operation with no preconditions).  And those are always safe operations for fundamental types like pointers.

Comment: Just use a `unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> is a guaranteed to point to NULL ?

No, it will be unchanged. Initialisation of built-in types will never modify the initialiser. Only initialisation of a class type with a move constructor (or an evil non-constant copy constructor, such as `auto_ptr`) could modify it.

For example, if you used `std::unique_ptr` rather than dumb pointers, then `a` would be empty after the initialisation of `b`.

> How about if `a` and `b` were ints?

Still no.

Comment: This is true in practice but does the standard forbid this from making a equal to null after the move? It might be useful for debugging purposes for example.

Comment: @jcoder: Yes, the standard does forbid it. Initialisation of an object not of class type (described in C++11 8.5/16, final bullet) doesn't involve anything that can modify the initialiser expression. It just evaluates the expression, and applies standard conversions if necessary. If you want pointers to be smart, you need to use smart pointer classes.

Answer (score 1):

Easy answer, a raw pointer is not a smart pointer, so no, moves on simple types will not clear the moved from value, or at least are not guaranteed to do that. Why should moving a raw pointer set a moved from value to `nullptr`? It doesn't have any notion of `delete` or that a double `delete` could be something evil or unwanted. Moving just guarantees to leave the object in a valid but unspecified state and making moving of simple types more complex and inefficient than copying would certainly be counterintuitive. Any semantics above *"store an address for me"* are up to special smart pointer types and out of the resposibility of a simple raw pointer.

Answer (score 0):

> Although note that -in the standard library- moving implies that the moved-from object is left in a valid but unspecified state. Which means that, after such an operation, **the value of the moved-from object should only be destroyed or assigned a new value; accessing it otherwise yields an unspecified value**

Quoted from -- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/move/

So in your pointer case, `a` is in an unspecified state, so it can contain anything. In order to use `a`, we need to give it a new value to point to

Comment: The value `a` is specified by the language.  It is unchanged by this assignment.

Comment: This answer is wrong. The quote has nothing to do with initialising built-in types from rvalue references, which is what the question is about. "Moving" only happens when calling a function (typically a move constructor/assignment operator) with an rvalue reference, and pointers don't have move constructors. `std::move` itself doesn't move anything; it just gives you a reference that can be moved from.